# Nested While Loop not working

Tags: php, arrays, json, while-loop

I am developing a webservice for and android app the webservice is in PHP fetching data from a MySQL database ... The problem that I am having is that some of the projects have multiple details but my code is only fetching one detail for every project. I am getting the data in JSON format.

You can check this [Here](http://projects.base29.com/webservice/?q=projects)

Here is my code

```
function requiredData(){

    $db = $this->dbConnection();
    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects JOIN project_details ON projects.project_id=project_details.project_id";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects";

    $queryResult = $db->query($sql);

        if($queryResult->num_rows > 0){

            while($row = $queryResult->fetch_assoc()){

                $pid = $row['project_id'];
                $detailsql = "SELECT * FROM project_details WHERE project_id=$pid";
                $sqlResult = $db->query($detailsql);
                if($sqlResult->num_rows > 0){
                    while ($d = $sqlResult->fetch_assoc()){
                        $r = array(
                            "project_id" => $d['project_id'],
                            "project_detail" => array(
                                "work_done" => $d['project_detail'],
                                "payment_for_work" => $d['project_payment'],
                                "payment_status" => $d['project_payment_status'],
                                "detail_id" => $d['project_detail_id']
                            )
                        );
                    }
                }
                $results[$row['project_name']] = array(
                   "project_id" => $row["project_id"],
                   "project_start_date" => $row["project_start_date"],
                   "project_due_date" => $row["project_due_date"],
                   "project_currency" => $row["project_currency"],
                   "project_work_details" => $r 
                );


            }
        }
       return $results;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What? I have checked the link you specified, it shows multiple projects. What exactly you want?

Comment: Some of the projects have multiple project_details ... but currently one is showing ... for example project id 20 has multiple project_detail array ,,, but there is only one showing up ...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the second `while` loop. You are assigning array to `$r`, and `$r` value overwrites every time.

So, I am assigning now array to an other array, So it will become 2 dimensional array, like this;

```
               while ($d = $sqlResult->fetch_assoc()){
                    $r[] = array(
                        "project_id" => $d['project_id'],
                        "project_detail" => array(
                            "work_done" => $d['project_detail'],
                            "payment_for_work" => $d['project_payment'],
                            "payment_status" => $d['project_payment_status'],
                            "detail_id" => $d['project_detail_id']
                        )
                    );
                }
```

Now you can use `$r`, it will have multiple details of the project.

Comment: I have already tested this when I use $r[ ] I get a infinite loop ... I have edited the code and replaced $r with $r[ ] for your this ... http://projects.base29.com/webservice/?q=projects

Comment: Using `$r[]`, there is nothing which can infinite the loop, It looks like there are too much records in your database. Did you try it by limit the select projects query?

Comment: Hmm .. Haven't tried limiting the records ... Didn't came to my mind .. Will try and let you know ...